# Center Vertical

Tags: android

I have this xml file to represent an element of my list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ItemList
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">


<android.support.wearable.view.CircledImageView
    android:id="@+id/ia"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/na"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    />

 </ItemList>
```

It contains one ImageView and one TextView. I want them to be centered vertically to each other. When TextView has a large text it is fine, but when the text has just one line the elements are not centered vertically. How can I make this?

Comment: put theme in LinearyLyaout (Vertical) and set gravity of LinearLayout to center_vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">


<android.support.wearable.view.CircledImageView
    android:id="@+id/ia"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/na"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ia"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ia"
    android:centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
/>
```

Use RelativeLayout and put `android:centerInParent="true"` on them children. Do not forget the `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ia"` and `android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ia"` on TextView